# Java: How to make RecyclerView item number change to the same number in Activity? (real time)

Tags: java, android

As the title says, I need to make RecyclerView item number, change to that same number, which is in that same Activity (in real-time). So when the number in Activity changes, also that number which is in the RecyclerView item, should change to that same number.

[image]

When the game starts, par number and those numbers in RecyclerView are the same as they should but ...

[image]

Now the 2nd hole par number changes to 3, but those RecyclerView item numbers are still 4, but instead, they should be also 3. How Can I make this change happen?

Here is my adapter:

```
@Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull GameViewHolder holder, int position) {
        GameItem currentItem = mGameList.get(position);

        holder.mTextPlayer.setText(currentItem.getText1());
        holder.mTextPar.setText(currentItem.getText2());

        /** If persons par number is smaller than course par number, then change persons par number background to blue **/
        if (Integer.parseInt(holder.mTextPar.getText().toString()) == 1) {
            holder.mTextPar.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.border_box_yellow);
        } else if (Integer.parseInt(holder.mTextPar.getText().toString()) < Integer.parseInt(ActivityGame.mParNm.getText().toString())) {
            holder.mTextPar.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.border_box_blue);
        } else if (Integer.parseInt(holder.mTextPar.getText().toString()) > Integer.parseInt(ActivityGame.mParNm.getText().toString())) {
            holder.mTextPar.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.border_box_red);
        } else if (Integer.parseInt(holder.mTextPar.getText().toString()) == Integer.parseInt(ActivityGame.mParNm.getText().toString())) {
            holder.mTextPar.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.border_box_green);
        }
```

Here in my GameAdapter, where I set those items background colors (according also to that par number) I tried to do:

```
holder.mTextPar.setText(ActivityGame.mParNm.getText().toString());
```

Meaning that I tried to set the number according to Par number, but it didn't change at all, it just changed the background of the items, but number stayed the same.

Comment: you at least need to call `notifyDataSetChanged()` on the `RecyclerVIew`'s adapter

Comment: Use DiffUtil to effectively update your RecyclerView. Here is an example
https://medium.com/@iammert/using-diffutil-in-android-recyclerview-bdca8e4fbb00

Comment: @ Vladyslav Matviienko when I add notifyDataSetChanged() my app crash, and crash report points to that notifyDataSetChanged()

Comment: Hey, I got the issue but I need to know the constructor and arraylist variable declared in the adapter so that I can post a proper answer of your issue.

Comment: I have posted my answer from the clue of your posted code snippet. I hope it will give you the solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do two simple things.

Create a method in the adapter-

```
public void updateAdapterData() {
    notifyDataSetChanged();
}
```

Next, add the below method in the activity and call it when there is a change in the par value in your activity.

```
private void updateGameArrayList(int parVal) {
    for(GameItem model : GameList) {
        model.setText2(parVal);
        adapterVariableInActivity.updateAdapterData();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to add a integer field in GameList Model that you fix at the time of adapter as same as activity value.

```
class GameList{
    String testPar;
    }
```

then if the text is changed in Activity you have to change the GameList objects of all List to current text of activity and call

```
// index in which you want to change text in list
gameList.get(index).setTestPar(currentTextOfActivityTextView);
adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
```

Answer (score 0):

These line of code worked for me.

**UPDATE THE DATA:** The only things I had to do is

```
myAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
```

1- You have to implement this in your adapter.

2- You had to do all of this in the **Actvity/Fragment** code not in the RecyclerView Adapter code.

I hope it helps you!